# Deformation Theory reference

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, deformation-theory

I was recommended a book by Oort sometime ago to read with reference to deformation theory, in particular in positive characteristic with hyperelliptic curves.

I couldn't find anything that seemed to be that relevant, I wondered if anyone would know what the book was?

Also, any general advice regarding deformation theory books would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Mumford's *Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface* is a wonderful book,
which develops ideas related to deformation theory (especially embedded deformations, as part of the infinitesimal theory of Hilbert schemes), and many
other fundamental topics in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much